# Can you programmatically map POJOs from other MongoDB collections in Java

Tags: java, mongodb, pojo

I'm experimenting with a 2D multiplayer RPG and looking into using MongoDB. However I'm struggling on mapping data. I can currently load a document to a pojo.

```
    mongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("game").withCodecRegistry(pojoCodecRegistry);

    final MongoCollection<Player> collection = mongoDatabase.getCollection("players", Player.class);
```

Player.Java:

```
public class Player {
    private ObjectId id;
    private String name;
    private List<Item> inventory;
    private List<Item> extendedStorage;

   // Getters & Setters
```

Item.java:

```
public class Item {
    private ObjectId id;

    private int itemId;
    private int quantity;
```

Now if I run collection.insertOne(player), it will save the items in the players collection, is their a way to instead save this into a "items" collection? And when I retrieve the Player, could I load the players object from the items collection?

Comment: That sounds more like using sql with 2 tables with common id instead of using mongodb. Anyway, of course it is possible but then you need to write your logic to handle those cases

Comment: It does a tad, would that be bad practice for Mongo?
The classes are basic at the moment, but if someone has a vast amount of items, each with various variables (quantity, durability, enchantments, etc) and 1000 users all have 1000s of items, wouldn't this become inefficient?

Comment: You have a point of course, but is it going to be easier or harder for you to keep the logic working. i.e I have 3 enchanted and 2 not enchanted swords in my inventory. How do you feel you need to query it?

Comment: Forgot to mention, you can store up to 16MB of data in a single document (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#BSON-Document-Size), if you think that is not enough to store for player, then I would say yes, you may need to separate.

Comment: Also, you may want to take a loot at document references, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/#document-references